# SPI HW testing (STM32MP157CAA)

Tags: spi

I have started looking into writing a test program/script to test the functionality of the one of the SPI bus interface (which in the current board called SPI6). I am trying to finish all the legwork before jump into writing the test. I am also waiting for the SPI slave hw to be available from the HW team. In the meantime I have done some searching in the code and in the internet. And I have found out some information regarding this. However, I have a doubt and I would like to request your help in that.

I looked into the kernel (the below is the STM kernel we are using at the moment):

```
# uname -a 
Linux buildroot 5.15.67 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 6 16:12:01 GMT 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I can see the following:

```
# ls -la /sys/bus/spi/devices/spi0.
spi0.0/ spi0.1/ spi0.2/ spi0.3/ spi0.4/

# ls -la /sys/class/spi_master/spi
spi0/ spi1/

# ls -la /sys/class/spi_
spi_master/ spi_slave/

# ls -la /sys/class/spi_master/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Feb 7 08:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 58 root root 0 Feb 7 08:18 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 7 10:01 spi0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/44004000.spi/spi_master/spi0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 7 10:01 spi1 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/5c001000.spi/spi_master/spi1

# ls -la /sys/class/spi_slave/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Feb 7 08:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 58 root root 0 Feb 7 08:18 ..
```

I checked the .config file we are using and the below config options are present:

```
CONFIG_SPI=y
CONFIG_SPI_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SPI_STM32=m
CONFIG_SPI_STM32_QSPI=y
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
```

I can also see the below module:

```
# lsmod | grep -i spi
spi_stm32 24576 0
```

However, I was expecting to see spi nodes under /dev which I cannot:

```
# ls -la /dev/spi*
ls: /dev/spi*: No such file or directory
```

I do not have any slave device attached to the bus yet. Can someone please suggest if there is anything I am missing here? Please ask for more information if needed if I have missed to mention anything which may help understand the question.

I am copying the SPI6 (the spi interface I am interested in) entries from the dts file below

```
&spi6{
        pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_pins_mx &spi6_pins_z_mx>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&spi6_sleep_pins_mx &spi6_sleep_pins_z_mx>;
        status = "okay";

        /* USER CODE BEGIN spi6 */
        /* USER CODE END spi6 */
};

        spi6_pins_mx: spi6_mx-0 {
                pins {
                        pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('G', 14, AF5)>; /* SPI6_MOSI */
                        bias-disable;
                        drive-push-pull;
                        slew-rate = <1>;
                };
        };

        spi6_sleep_pins_mx: spi6_sleep_mx-0 {
                pins {
                        pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('G', 14, ANALOG)>; /* SPI6_MOSI */
                };
        };

        spi6_pins_z_mx: spi6_mx-0 {
                pins {
                        pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 0, AF8)>, /* SPI6_SCK */
                                         <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 1, AF8)>; /* SPI6_MISO */
                        bias-disable;
                        drive-push-pull;
                        slew-rate = <1>;
                };
        };

        spi6_sleep_pins_z_mx: spi6_sleep_mx-0 {
                pins {
                        pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 0, ANALOG)>, /* SPI6_SCK */
                                         <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 1, ANALOG)>; /* SPI6_MISO */
                };
        };
```

I have now added the following child in the spi6 entry in both the u-boot and the kernel dts fileas as below:

```
&spi6{
        pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_pins_mx &spi6_pins_z_mx>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&spi6_sleep_pins_mx &spi6_sleep_pins_z_mx>;
        status = "okay";

        /* USER CODE BEGIN spi6 */
        spidev@0{
            compatible = "st,stm32h7-spi";
            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
        };
        /* USER CODE END spi6 */
};
```

Now I can see the kernel log showing the child has been registered:

```
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.debug kernel: [    4.443136] spi_stm32 5c001000.spi: 8 x 8-bit fifo size
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.debug kernel: [    4.443179] spi_stm32 5c001000.spi: 16-bit maximum data frame
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.debug kernel: [    4.443921] spi_stm32 5c001000.spi: registered master spi1
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.debug kernel: [    4.444284] spi spi1.0: setup mode 0, 8 bits/w, 1000000 Hz max --> 0
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.debug kernel: [    4.450214] spi_stm32 5c001000.spi: registered child spi1.0
Feb  8 14:46:31 buildroot user.info kernel: [    4.450270] spi_stm32 5c001000.spi: driver initialized (master mode)
```

However, when I check /dev/ the child doesn't show up in the list:

```
# ls -la /dev/s
shm/    stderr  stdin   stdout
```

I am not sure about the below string in the part which I have added in my dts file:

```
compatible = "st,stm32h7-spi";
```

I copied it from a grep I did for stm32mpu and found this was used for spi6. Does this have any impact?

Additonal information: CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV is set in the kernel config:

```
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
```

Comment: Are any of the SPI busses enabled in the devicetree ?

Comment: Please edit the question with the relevant dts segments instead of adding as comments

Comment: Added the dts entries for SPI6 in the question now.

Comment: `spi6` has no child nodes. See [an example](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_use_SPI_from_Linux_userland_with_spidev#DT_and_kernel_configuration)

Comment: @droptop did the suggested change and updated the question with those additional bits. But still cannot see any spi* under /dev. As you can see from the kernel log I have pasted the child spi1.0 has been registered by the kernel but it doesn't show up in the /dev entries unfortunately.

Comment: Try `compatible = "linux,spidev"`. And make sure `CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV` is enabled in your kernel config.

Comment: Thanks I have now changed it to compatible = "linux,spidev". And yes the CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV is also enabled (config out from the stm32 is pasted in the bottom of the question just now).

Comment: At this moment I am looking to carry out a loopback test by connecting the MISO and the MOSI pins of the SPI6. For that I guess I do not need to attach a slave device to see the nodes under /dev? I don't see any reason but still wanted to double check.

Comment: I finally managed to get it working. I had to change the spi6 child node exactly matching the entry as described in the following link: https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_use_SPI_from_Linux_userland_with_spidev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following what @droptop suggested to add a child node under the spi6 dts entry, I could finally manage to get this working using the following entry described in the STM link: https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_use_SPI_from_Linux_userland_with_spidev

```
kernel/stm32mp157c-ccb-mx.dts
&spi6{
        pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_pins_mx &spi6_pins_z_mx>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&spi6_sleep_pins_mx &spi6_sleep_pins_z_mx>;
        status = "okay";

        /* USER CODE BEGIN spi6 */
        spidev@0{
            compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
        };
        /* USER CODE END spi6 */
};

and also in 
CA7/DeviceTree/ccb/u-boot/stm32mp157c-ccb-mx.dts
&spi6{
        pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
        pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_pins_mx &spi6_pins_z_mx>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&spi6_sleep_pins_mx &spi6_sleep_pins_z_mx>;
        status = "okay";

        /* USER CODE BEGIN spi6 */
        spidev@0{
            compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <4000000>;
        };
        /* USER CODE END spi6 */
};
```

My kernel configuration was as following:

```
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep  -w CONFIG_SPI
CONFIG_SPI=y
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep  -w CONFIG_SPI_MASTER
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep  -w CONFIG_SPI_STM32
CONFIG_SPI_STM32=m
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep  -w CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
# cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip | grep  -w CONFIG_SPI_DEBUG
CONFIG_SPI_DEBUG=y
```

After I did this I could see the spi child node under the /dev as follows:

```
# ls -la /dev/spidev1.0 
crw-rw----    1 root     root      153,   0 Feb  8 19:22 /dev/spidev1.0
```

Just to check if this works I ran spidev_test and I can see this:

```
# spidev_test -D /dev/spidev1.0 -v
spi mode: 0x0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)
TX | FF FF FF FF FF FF 40 00 00 00 00 95 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 0D  | ......@....�..................�.
RX | FF FF FF FF FF FF 40 00 00 00 00 95 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 0D  | ......@....�..................�.
```

Thanks a lot to @droptop for directing me towards the right direction.